# How to find pid of an application recently run on linux?

Tags: linux, process, embedded

Hi I recently run an application or an app and now I want to know the cpu status info so i need the PID of the application i have run recently. But i have so many PIDs in the /proc directory so how can i know the PID of the particular application for example "my-example" application binary i recently executed.

Comment: Do you mean an application that you *started* recently and that's still running, or an application that exited recently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some command line tools for process management you can check:

- You can use `pidof <name>`, e.g. `pidof bash`, to get the PID of a process given the program name
- You can use `ps -aux` to get a listing of currently running programs with their starting time and PID. You may look for your program in the listing.
- You can use `ps -eafx` to get a listing of running programs showing all the command line options. May be you can find your program looking for some command-line option or parameter.
- You can use `pgrep [options] <patterns>` to look for a process using multiple criteria. You can run `pgrep --help` to review all the options.

Comment: pidof <my-example> has worked. And i did `cat status` to see the status of the task But it is showing that is in sleep state and I am not sure whether those statistics belong to current state or for the previous run? Is it for recent run of the application?I understood that i have to login into it on ssh on ethernet and run the application through logging into console using putty and observe the performance while it is running from ssh terminal window. Any ways thanks.

Comment: In `ps`, you can use `-o` to output some values and `-C` to select a program. For instance, you can use `ps -o pid,stime,stat,command -C bash` to get the PID, starting time, status and command line for the running `bash` programs in your session. -- these values are for the current status of the program. Note that a program may change of status, e.g. when it is waiting for I/O, during its execution.

Answer (score 1):

With the interactive command line tool `htop` you can search (F3) for a process and you're directly given some basic CPU info as well as the PID.

Answer (score 0):

#### First variant

Run your application by this way in the terminal:

```
$ my-example &      # put the program in the background
$ echo $!           # print the program's PID
```

`$!` - Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background.

For more information look in the `man bash`, the **Special Parameters** section.

#### Second variant

If application already started, do `pgrep my-example`. It will return the `my-example` PID.

Comment: I am running linux on my embedded system. When i gave above command the application is breaking after executing the statements. It shouldnot happen. Because this when i run this application the ethernet ports will receive data packets on udp but this command `echo $!` is breaking the application run. How can i know immediately after the application run?

Comment: @jenny What about second variant?

Comment: it gave a message `command not found`